# The name for the quotient property

Tags: gn.general-topology

I asked this question on math@stackoverflow and was suggested to ask it here as well.

We call a surjective $f:X\rightarrow Y$ a quotient mapping if it satisfies, for every $U\subset Y$

> (continuity, $f$ is continuous) $U$ is open $\Rightarrow$ $f^{-1}(U)$ is open

and

> (???) $f^{-1}(U)$ is open $\Rightarrow$ $U$ is open.

I was wondering if there is a name for the second property itself of the definition, or should I just call it "the other" property?

And if a function satisfies this property only, how should I call it?

Comment: What is (if any) the relation of (???) with the usual concept of *open map*? I mean, continuity + (???) imply that $f$ is open?

Comment: I think it's not quite the same as openness: you do not require that the image of **any** open set should be open. Why do you need a name? It doesn't seem to make much sense without the continuity, and with continuity, you already know the name :)

Comment: Sometimes it is said that $f$ is open with respect to saturated sets (i.e. sets of the form $f^{-1}(A)$).

Comment: @FrancescoPolizzi In this context openness (or closeness) is stronger in the sense that if a function is surjective continuous + open (or close) then it is a quotient map, but not vice versa.

Comment: @FrancescoPolizzi Consider $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow S^1$ given by $(\cos 2\pi x,\sin 2\pi x)$, this is a surjective, continuous and open map, so quotient, but it is not closed. Now restrict the same function to domain $[0,1]$, it is now surjective, continuous and closed map, so still quotient, but not open. An example from Munkres, the projection from $\mathbb{R}^2$ to $x$-axis restricted to domain $\mathbb{R}\times\{0\}\cup[0,+\infty)\times\mathbb{R}$ is a non-open non-closed quotient.

Comment: @AlexDegtyarev In many cases it would just be convenient to call a function that is known to satisfy this property, but not necessary continuous, call it something without rewriting the property every time.

Comment: @RamirodelaVega Yes, this is what I saw, so it seems to be the best (or, at least, the only) name for the property. If you put it as an answer, and no one suggests something else, I will accept it as the answer. Thanks!